# How to resize the text box depending upon the swf in flash?

Tags: flash, textbox, height, stage

in that i have a text box.when i enlarge the swf window the size of swf is large.In that time i want to resize the textbox.how to do this?

i need to adjus the x,y ,width and height depend upon the stage height and width.

**update**

when i resize the window it looks like that
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

_resize();

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, _resize);
function _resize(e:Event = null):void
{
    tbox.x = 0;
    tbox.y = 0;
    tbox.width = stage.stageWidth;
    tbox.height = stage.stageHeight;
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me.. Might need more information about what you've done.

Comment: i want to resize the textbox width,height,x,y,depending upon the swf stage once again i will update my question with image

Comment: Yep so that's what it does... Here's the source files for testing: http://martywallace.com/testing/tbox.zip (Type into the text box and then resize to watch the text wrap onto new lines to fit etc).

Comment: i apply stage color and run,i didnt see the stage in ur example.Sorry for my english.Can you understand my question?